# Como paro um programa em execução?

Tags: c#

Eu criei um programa que compacta arquivos usando `7z` e como são vários arquivos dentro de um loop e o programa deve compactar 1 arquivo por vez, eu usei **`WaitForExit()`**

O programa funciona perfeitamente, mas agora gostaria de colocar um botão cancelar e não estou conseguindo, pois acredito que o **`WaitForExit()`** não deixa eu clicar no botão até que tenha terminado o processo.

Como eu posso fazer esse botão cancelar?

O meu codigo:

```
foreach (string currentFile in txtFiles)
{
    game = PastaDestino + 
Path.GetFileName(currentFile).Replace(Path.GetExtension(currentFile), "") + 
".7z";
    bin = currentFile;
    cue = currentFile.Replace(Path.GetExtension(currentFile), "") + ".cue";
    command = String.Format("a -t7z \"{0}\" \"{1}\" \"{2}\" -mx=9", game, 
bin, cue);

p = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "7z.exe",
    Arguments = command,
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
};

    x = Process.Start(p);
    x.WaitForExit();
}
```

obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para matar o processo voce pode chamar `process.Kill();`

Contudo o truque está em nao chamar `WaitForExit` uma vez que esse método vai esperar até o processo terminar e dessa forma vai também bloquear a sua interfáce gráfica.

Por outras palavras voce tem que subscrever ao evento `Exited`.

Devido ao funcionamento do `7zip` voce tem a restricao de lancar apenas um processo de cada vez para adicionar um arquivo ao ficheiro zip. Isso tem implicacoes em termos de código. Voce nao pode simplesmente percorrer os ficheiros. Voce tem que lancar o processo novamente apenas quando o processo anterior terminar.

De cada vez que um ficheiro for adicionado voce pode também ter uma barra de progresso. Este mecanismo de notificação de progresso servirá também para determinar quando o processo de adicionar todos os arquivos ao zip concluiu.

Neste particular algoritmo eu nao permito o cancelamento do processo própriamente dito. Eu simplesmente paro de adicionar ficheiros ao arquivo.
O que isto quer dizer é caso voce tenha arquivos bastante grandes entao o cancelamento só será processado assim que esse arquivo for adicionado.

Uma forma de fazer isso é a seguinte:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IProgress<int>
{
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellation;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ZipFiles(IList<string> files, IProgress<int> progress, CancellationToken token)
    {
        Process Zip(string file)
        {
            var cue = Path.ChangeExtension(file, ".cue");
            var process = new Process()
            {
                EnableRaisingEvents = true,
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "7z.exe",
                    Arguments = $"a zip.7z {file} {cue}",
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                }
            };
            process.Start();
            return process;
        }

        var count = 0;
        void Handler(object o, EventArgs a)
        {
            var p = o as Process;
            if (_cancellation.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (count < files.Count)
            {
                var next = Zip(files[count]);
                count++;
                next.Exited += Handler;
            }
            progress.Report(count * 100 / files.Count);
            p.Exited -= Handler;
        }
        {
            var process = Zip(files[count]);
            process.Exited += Handler;
        }
    }

    private void btnZip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnZip.Enabled = false;
        _cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\code", "*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Take(100)
            .ToList();
        ZipFiles(files, this, _cancellation.Token);
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _cancellation.Cancel();
        progressBar.Value = 0;
        btnZip.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void Report(int value)
    {
        Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            progressBar.Value = value;
            if (value == 100)
            {
                btnZip.Enabled = true;
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

O melhor mesmo seria meter os arquivos todos que quer arquivar dentro duma estrutura, uma vez que o [`7zip` permite-lhe arquivar os arquivos duma diretoria](https://superuser.com/q/340046). Dessa forma o seu código ficaria mais simples.

```
7z a c:\archive3.zip dir2\dir3\
```

Mas caso necessite de diretorias diferentes entao o código que eu forneci deverá resolver.

Comment: Entao como falei matar o processo eu sei, mas o programa nao deixa ele fica travado ele só libera o acesso ao botao depois que termina, gostaria de poder cancelar o processo, mas se eu nao usar o WaitForExit nao funciona, pode ser que eu esteja fazendo algo errado, mas o meu programa pega uma lista e uso o foreach dai cada laço do foreach quero que ele compacte um arquivo e esses arquivos sao grandes e demorados, se nao uso o Wait ele roda todo loop e nao compacta nada

Comment: @FabyoGuimaraes Se complementar a sua pergunta com um [mcve] será possivel ajuda-lo a antigir o seu objetivo.

Comment: obrigado Bruno, mas o codigo que postei é basicamente só isso o resto do codigo sao verificações, try etc, o programa lista um conteudo de uma pasta roda o loop e executa o 7z, minha duvida esta nesse bloco de codigo dentro do loop eu preciso executar um comando e chamar o 7z para compactar o arquivo que o loop esta lendo como compactação é um processo demorado eu usei o WaitForExit, porque se nao usar o loop atropela tudo e chama o 7z tudo de uma vez e nao funciona nao compacta nada, minha duvida é que mesmo colocando o botao de cancelar ele nao responde só no final quando termina tudo

Comment: @FabyoGuimaraes Atualizei minha resposta. Na minha aplicacao tenho 2 butoes e uma barra de progresso. Nada disso é necessário mesmo. O que lhe interessa é o método `ZipFiles`

Comment: Muito Obrigado Bruno, entendi sua ideia e estou tentando colocar ela pra funcionar, mas esta dando erro System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'O índice estava fora do intervalo. Ele deve ser não-negativo e menor que o tamanho da coleção. Zip(files[count]); o count esta com valor 0, mas vou tentar corrigir só estou dando um retorno

Comment: Bruno deu certo seu codigo, só tem um detalhe quando eu clico em cancelar o programa para na hora mas percebi que o processo continua em execução, percebi isso porque eu fui deletar o 7z.zip e o windows nao deixou dai fui ver o 7z.exe estava em execução e continuando o trabalho, obrigado pelas dicas, só estou dando um retorno mas vou tentar resolver esse problema, valeu

Comment: Pessoal que me ajudou muito obrigado, @Bruno Costa para esse topico nao ficar muito extenso foi dar como resolvido, e com sua resposta deu certo de fazer o que queria, agora que estou tento outros problemas relacionados iriei criar um outro topico focado nesse novo problema, obrigado

Answer (score 2):

```
x.Close()
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/CloseProcess.cs).

Sempre leia a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.close?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) completa quando for usar um componente.

Obviamente que ele só será executado no momento que for possível. O `WaitForExit()` impedirá qualquer coisa de ser executada até o fim do processo.

O ideal quando quer fazer algo assim é usar uma API em vez de lançar um processo que você não tem controle

Comment: Entao mas minha aplicação ela nao responde eu clico em cima do botao e nao deixa clicar é como se nao tivesse respondendo, acredito que deva ser o WaitForExit que faz isso, parar o processo em si eu sei fazer mas o problema é que nao deixa apertar o botao e se eu nao usar o WaitForExit ele nao funciona e nao compacta os arquivos

Answer (score 1):

Esse tipo de sincronia entre threads é facinho:

```cs
    public class Compressor
    {
        static object @lock = new object();
        static bool parar = false;
        static Process atual = null;
        public static async Task<bool> Comprimir(IEnumerable<string> txtFiles, string PastaDestino, string game, string bin, string cue)
        {
            bool completo = true;
            
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                string command = "";
                Process x;
                ProcessStartInfo p;

                foreach (string currentFile in txtFiles)
                {
                    if (parar)
                    {
                        completo = false;
                        break;
                    }
                        
                    game = PastaDestino +
                    Path.GetFileName(currentFile).Replace(Path.GetExtension(currentFile), "") +
                ".7z";
                    bin = currentFile;
                    cue = currentFile.Replace(Path.GetExtension(currentFile), "") + ".cue";
                    command = String.Format("a -t7z \"{0}\" \"{1}\" \"{2}\" -mx=9", game, bin, cue);

                    p = new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        FileName = "7z.exe",
                        Arguments = command,
                        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                    };

                    
                    lock(@lock)
                    {
                        x = Process.Start(p);
                        atual = x;
                    }
                    x.WaitForExit();
                    lock(@lock)
                    {
                        atual = null;
                    }
                }
                lock(@lock)
                {
                    atual = null;
                }
            });

            return completo;
        }

        public static void Parar()
        {
            lock(@lock)
            {
                parar = true;
                if(atual != null)
                {
                    try {atual.Kill();} catch {} // Só para garantir em caso de erro
                }
            }
        }

        public static void Reset()
        {
            parar = false;
            atual = null;
        }
    }
```

Para rodar:

```cs
Compressor.Comprimir(arquivos, "destino", "game", "bin", "cue");
```

Para parar:

```cs
Compressor.Parar();
```

Para usá-lo novamente:

```
Compressor.Reset();
```

Não esqueça de limpar o arquivo interrompido se for o caso.