# Problema ao cancelar um processo

Tags: c#, processo

[Coloquei uma pergunta anteriormente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/298706/como-paro-um-programa-em-execu%C3%A7%C3%A3o/298712#298712) para fazer o cancelamento do processo de comprimir arquivos.

Tenho 2 problemas com esse código, o programa tem a função de compactar arquivos em pares separadamente ficando 2 arquivos em cada 7z, os arquivos são bin,cue utilizando 7z, eu tenho uma pasta cheia desses arquivos e queria compactar eles

Os problemas são:

1. Quando rodo o programa e clico em cancelar o programa para mas o 7z continua na memoria trabalhando.
2. Quando o programa finaliza eu percebo que ele ainda esta compactando o ultimo arquivo, parece que o programa avisa que concluiu mas ele não esperou a ultima tarefa ser concluída

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IProgress<int>
{
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellation;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ZipFiles(IList<string> files, IProgress<int> progress, CancellationToken token)
    {
        Process x;

        Process Zip(string file)
        {
            string game = Path.ChangeExtension(file, null) + ".7z";
            string cue = Path.ChangeExtension(file, ".cue");
            x = new Process()
            {
                EnableRaisingEvents = true,
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "7z.exe",
                    Arguments = String.Format("a -t7z \"{0}\" \"{1}\" \"{2}\" -mx=9", game, file, cue),
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                }
            };

            x.Start();
            return x;
        }

        var count = 0;
        void Handler(object o, EventArgs a)
        {
            var p = o as Process;
            if (_cancellation.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                x.Close();
                x.Kill();
                return;
            }
            if (count < files.Count)
            {
                var next = Zip(files[count]);
                count++;
                next.Exited += Handler;
            }
            progress.Report(count * 100 / files.Count);
            p.Exited -= Handler;
        }
        {
            var process = Zip(files[count]);
            process.Exited += Handler;
        }
    }

    public void Report(int value)
    {
        Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            progressBar.Value = value;
            if (value == 100)
            {
                btnZip.Enabled = true;
            }
        }));
    }

    private void btnZip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnZip.Enabled = false;
        _cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\Fabyo.GALUTTI\Desktop\p", "*.bin", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Take(100)
            .ToList();
        ZipFiles(files, this, _cancellation.Token);
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _cancellation.Cancel();
        progressBar.Value = 0;
        btnZip.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu já resolvi 99% do deu problems é o seu dever de o meter a funcionar para as suas necessidades especificas. Demonstra claramente falta de esforco.

Comment: Bruno eu tentei e estou tentando, ja fiz varias tentativas sem sucesso, nao é falta de esforço, eu sou programador de php, nao conheço nada de c#, estou querendo aprender mas tem coisas que pra mim é mais dificil, nao quero que ninguem faça nada por mim, só pedi uma ajuda, ou uma orientação

Comment: @BrunoCosta Desculpe por parecer que nao estava tendo algum esforço, mas pelo contrario, eu quero fazer esse programa funciona e aprender, comprei ate um curso na udemy, e pesquisei bastante, e tentei usar BackgroundWorker e nao deu certo, nos testes que eu fiz simulando um loop com sleep funciona certinho, cancela normal, mas quando vou rodar o processo com 7z, agora ele esta rodando direto e terminando em segundos ou seja ele nao esta fazendo o que precisa fazer, tentei usar delegates, HasExited, mas como falei sou novo em c#, mas quando mais dificil fica mais eu estou gostando de aprender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode melhorar o seu processo de cancelamento para matar o processo. Quando um processo for morto novos processos não serão começados.

Provavelmente poderão haver formas mais elegantes de resolver o problema. Neste caso estou a adicionar os processos a uma lista e no processo de cancelamento percorro a lista para matar os processos.

A lista é retornada em forma de objecto (foi a forma mais estúpida que encontrei para abstrair) e esse mesmo objecto deve ser passado ao processo de cancelamento. Se não tiver satisfeito pode sempre retornar a lista propriamente dita.

```
public class Zip
{
    public object ZipFiles(IList<string> files, IProgress<int> progress)
    {
        Process Zip(string file)
        {
            var process = new Process()
            {
                EnableRaisingEvents = true,
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "7z.exe",
                    Arguments = $"a zip.7z {file}",
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                }
            };
            process.Start();
            return process;
        }

        var processes = new ConcurrentBag<Process>();
        var count = 0;
        void Handler(object o, EventArgs a)
        {
            var p = o as Process;
            try
            {
                if (p.ExitCode != 0)
                {
                    return;
                }
                if (count < files.Count)
                {
                    var next = Zip(files[count]);
                    processes.Add(next);
                    count++;
                    next.Exited += Handler;
                }
                progress.Report(count * 100 / files.Count);
            }
            finally
            {
                p.Exited -= Handler;
            }
        }
        {
            var process = Zip(files[count]);
            processes.Add(process);
            process.Exited += Handler;
        }
        return processes;
    }

    public void Cancel(object token)
    {
        var processes = token as IEnumerable<Process>;
        foreach (var p in processes)
        {
            if (!p.HasExited)
            {
                p.Kill();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Ultimamente você pode sempre ter uma situação onde o arquivo está sendo utilizado por um curto espaço de tempo e o sistema operativo não o deixará eliminar o seu arquivo. Não há absolutamente nada que você possa fazer para impedir isso.